# Weak convergence of Poisson distributed random variables

Tags: normal-distribution, weak-convergence, poisson-distribution

I am stucked in the middle of an exercise:

Let $$X_n,Y_m$$ independent random variables having the Poisson distribution with parameters n and m respectively. Show that $$\frac{(X_n-n)-(Y_m-m)}{\sqrt{X_n+Y_m}} \; \;\underrightarrow{\omega} \;\; N(0,1) \;\mbox{as}\;n,m \rightarrow \infty $$

My problem is the sum in the denominator (for $n+m$ instead, it is an easy exercise because I can split the random variables in several Poisson(1) distributed r.v's and make use of the independence).

Comment: Maybe write it as a product $\frac{(X_n-n)-(Y_m-m)}{\sqrt{n+m}}\times \frac{\sqrt{n+m}}{\sqrt{X_n+Y_m}} $ The first term goes to a standard normal and the second term goes to $1$ as $n,m \to \infty$